# Global constants in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

Is there a way to define constants in PHPUnit that can be used in all your test suites? For example, say I want to be able to test on jason.dev.mysite.com sometimes and jim.dev.mysite.com sometimes, and maybe specify when I run the command on which site I want to test. Is anything like this possible?

The closest thing I found was this: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/appendixes.configuration.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be in the bootstrap file.

Check here : http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html for the bootstrap file option.

You can also check out the `setUp()` and `setUpBeforeClass()` methods, but they are related to one test class only.

Answer (score 5):

For those who already have a bootstrap and are wanting to define a constant separately checkout the `<php>` tag in the [XML Configuration file](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.2/configuration.html#the-php-element). The link seem to change on a regular basis with version updates so an example is:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="../libraries/global/bootstrap.lib.php">
    <php>
        <env name="db_user" value="admin"/>
        <env name="db_pass" value="admin"/>
        <env name="db_host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
        <env name="db_port" value="1433"/>
        <const name="DEBUG" value="FALSE"/>
    </php>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="role">
            <file>modules/role/role.test.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: How to read a value from an environment variable and set it as constant here?

Comment: You can't. That is specifically what this answer is addressing.